# iOS Search Bar with 2 Input Fields (like name to search for and 2nd line for location where to search)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uisearchbar

I'am currently in the progress of developing an iPhone App where the user can search for places a) next to him and b) wherever he want's to search for.

My problem is that I have no idea how to grant the user the possibility to provide the user a search bar like in the "YELP"-App with two lines in which can be entered i.e. any name he's looking for and 2nd the place where to search for (location).

I've tried to find some solution with Google but unfortunately without any success.

I'd appreciate any hints or help - maybe there's a tutorial out there or anybody has had the same issue?

Thank's in advance,
Leo

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with custom component. Use two textfield one for name one for location search. Delegate textfield in your view.

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you - but I really have no idea how to start for this?? Could you provide me with an example please? Would be more than great!